# will gridview paging makes the web page loads faster?

Tags: c#, asp.net, paging

I am binding data in a gridview in page load with paging control, since I don't have much experience working with gridview so I am looking for a guidance that if I give paging in the gridivew, say 10 record per page then will my page load faster in comparison to gridview without paging? I am sorry if I could not keep my point of my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

My Answer is `NO` because if you do `datatable to datagrid datasource` it's all the same..Only the difference is you are `controlling` the `data` to show in `datagrid`.. but the truth is all of your data has been `loaded already` in your `datagrid control` same with if you wanted to use `paging` or `without paging.`

Comment: One more thing to make you slow as you've said if you have a bulk of data and it also depend on your machine specs.. and the connection between your working pc to your Database if it is in a server.

Comment: oh okay, did not know of it really worthy sharing! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:

Enabling paging for your `GridView` will make your page load faster. But you will only notice it when you already have large data, say ten thousands of rows with 10+ columns. Usually your application will even throw an `Out of Memory` exception while loading your page with `GridView`.

So to be safe and efficient, if you have large data, definitely use paging.

Comment: Oh okay but I was thinking, I don't know if I am sounding stupid but thought to ask here, why facebook isn't using paging?

Comment: Facebook is using it, it's just not obvious. Facebook detects when the user reached the end of the page, and loads the next 'page' without requiring you to click anything.